# How to handle ConcurrentModificationException in Android

Tags: java, android, exception, arraylist

Im trying to delete item from a `ArrayList`. *Some times* it pops an exception, `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

First I tried to remove them by `array_list_name.remove(i)`, but it failed and some people were asked to use Iterator instead. So my current code is as follows:

```
for (Iterator<Collectable> iter = array_list_name.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
   Collectable s = iter.next();
   if (s.equals(array_list_name.get(id))){
       iter.remove();
       return true;
   }
}
```

And I call `array_list_name` inside `onDraw()` function in view. My view is a `SurfaceView`. Can anyone suggest me how to delete items from `ArrayList` without getting this error?

Comment: Problem is unclear to me - you actually use `iter.remove()` **and** see CME, not always but sometimes?

Comment: CME = java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: Are there any other threads accessing the ArrayList while your iterator is active?

Comment: onDraw() runs on a separate thread and item removal occurs in another. No other threads are used.

Comment: but the onDraw() method could be called concurrently, right?

Comment: Yes, `onDraw` is called in the UI thread so it might be invoked at the same time as item removal in the other thread.

Comment: So that is the problem, see the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29): `The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `ArrayList`

Comment: I would only recommend that if there are few modifications, otherwise a manual copy would be better.

Answer (score 7):

Seems from the comments that your `ArrayList<Collectable>` is accessed from the `onDraw()` method in one thread, by the UI, concurrently with you removing items from it in another thread.

So, why not just wrap both accessors in a

```
synchronized(array_list_name)
{
    // UI access code or item removal code
}
```

Note that this might make your UI laggy if removing items takes a long time. If this is the case, consider making a list of all item indexes to be removed, and remove them in a tight synchronized loop after iterating over the whole list.

**Update**

It seems to me your whole code snippet could be simplified to just:

```
synchronized(array_list_name)
    return array_list_name.remove(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever thought to use [Vector List](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Vector.html) ?  If you need a thread-safe implementation, you should use `Vector` instead of `ArrayList`.
`Vector` list's usage is same with `ArrayList`. Just change its type with `Vector`.

> Unsafe usage

```
ArrayList<FutureTask> futureTasks;
```

> Change with

```
Vector<FutureTask> futureTasks;
```

That's all.

Comment: This is by far the best answer on this thread. Using a class as ```Vector``` that was intented precisely for concurrent usage is the right solution. I've already used in my own project, where I faced a similar problem and was getting ```ConcurrentModificationException```s. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a defensive copy of the list like so:

```
List copy = new ArrayList(array_list_name);
for (Iterator<Collectable> iter = copy.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
   Collectable s = iter.next();
   if (s.equals(copy.get(id))){
       iter.remove();
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: But this removes the element in the `copy`. The asker might want the element removed in `array_list_name`. If you remove it by its index you can't be sure you get the right element, because the List might have changed.