# Have ConcurrentModificationException even with synchronized keyword used

Tags: android, list, exception, object, concurrency

I have a list my defined object that return from a network service ( network svc will update this list).
At a certain point of time, I want to render what I have already had in that this on my listview.
I have following code:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = MyService.getInstance().getListOfMyObject()
```

And because I have another thread which will updated myObjects list, so I want to avoid concurrency modification exception.
I have:

```
 List<MyObject> clonedList = null;
 synchronized(myObjects){
         clonedList = MyListUtils.cloneList(myObjects)
 }
```

cloneList() function in MyListUtils is implemented in a simple way:

```
public static <T extends ICloneable<T>> List<T> cloneList(final List<T> source){
    List<T> result  = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T t : source){
       T newObject = t.clone();
       result.add(newObject);
    }
    return result;
}
```

-Dont care about ICloneable interface, I use this ICloneable to mark thing.

And I was given this exception

```
03-11 16:07:11.370: E/AndroidRuntime(8076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 16:07:11.370: E/AndroidRuntime(8076): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
03-11 16:07:11.370: E/AndroidRuntime(8076):  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:569)
03-11 16:07:11.370: E/AndroidRuntime(8076):  at xxx.utilities.MyListUtils.cloneList(CollectionUtils.java:120)
```

I don't know what's wrong with it? I did not call any function to modify object,I just "clone" it, as far as I know this doesn't change any single bit in my object.
Any idea is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per some thread I was able to find like [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in Android animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151956/problem-with-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-in-android-animation) and [How to handle ConcurrentModificationException in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621991/how-to-handle-concurrentmodificationexception-in-android)

If you are iterating over the list and at the same time some other thread is also modyfing it.. this would also cause the `ConcurrentModificationException`.. So you might try with `sychronizing` the `cloneList` method on the passed object of the list..

```
synchronized(source)
{
    // make a copy
}
```

I am hoping that you are already doing this in the thread that is modifying the data...

Comment: yes, I did it ( as you can see in my editted post), I have put my source inside a synchronized block. But it still throws exception.

Comment: can you also post the code that is modifying the data... are you synchronizing that part also...

Comment: MyService.getInstance().updateListOfMyObject()  --> this function is where I modify data ( I upate new data from network connection).

I have a list of object to cache my objects there, for updating new object and to  retrieve

Comment: can you please post the relevant code from `updateListOfMyObject()` method?

Comment: I just read data from network connection, then rebuild into object , then update these new object into the list cached in MyService.

Comment: so when you update the list are you using the `synchronized(cached_list_object)` for the code that updates the list with the new objects..

Comment: yes, I do use that sync keyword with my cached_list_object in MyService

Comment: I think I found it, even though I use synchronized keyword in my update function, but in my return function (in MyService) , I miss that. 
After add it to return function than things get into right track now :) 
Thanks for help @Praful Bhatnagar